# How to connect MSSQL database with the Zend Framework 3 in windows 7 machine?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv, zend-framework3

I'm trying to connect MSSQL database with Zend framework 3.

But I have connected  MSSQL with normal PHP code in my windows machine. For this I have installed sqlsrv.

Here is the code for that..

```
$serverName = "USER-PC\MYINSTANCE"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MYSamples", "UID"=>"MYRawData", "PWD"=>"123456");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Please help me to connect the MSSQL database with Zend framework 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, could you update your question to reflect that you're using Doctrine to handle the connection/data transfers between your application and the MS SQL Server? (There's a reasonable difference between setting up the connection yourself using `zendframework/zend-db` vs `doctrine/doctrine-orm-module`)

Comment: @rkeet Thank you for the suggestion, but I couldn't find the edit button for this question. Please help me to update this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally I have got answer. May be this answer help some one.

I have made below changes on local.php (config\autoload\local.php) file

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\Driver as SQLSrvDriver;

return [
   'doctrine' => [
       'connection' => [
           'orm_default' => [
               'driverClass' => SQLSrvDriver::class,
               'params' => [
                   'host'     => 'USER-PC\MYINSTANCE',                    
                   'user'     => 'MYRawData',
                   'password' => '123456',
                   'dbname'   => 'MYSamples',
                   'port'     => '49166'
               ]
           ],            
       ],        
   ],
];
```

Please refer this link to find the mssql port number : [Identify Port used by SQL Server Database Engine Using SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/)

Answer (score 0):

The 'sqlsrv' PHP extension must be installed.

```
Zend_Db::factory('sqlsrv', 
    array(
        'host'     => '<server_ip>',
        'username' => '<db_username>',
        'password' => '<db_password>',
        'dbname'   => '<db_name>',
        'charset'  => 'utf8'
    )
);
```

The 'dblib' pdo plugin must be installed.

```
Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_mssql', 
    array(
        'pdoType'  => 'dblib',
        'host'     => '<server_ip>',
        'username' => '<db_username>',
        'password' => '<db_password>',
        'dbname'   => '<db_name>'
    )
);
```

To work with 'dblib' you need to install https://www.freetds.org/userguide/.

Comment: Sorry, this comment is for ZF1.x versions. Still, it might be useful if someone needs it :)